# Downloadable APA Format Quick Style in Microsoft Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

Is there a downloadable APA format Quick Style for Microsoft Word 2010?  Instead of the default styles, I would like to have the default styles be in APA format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this Word Template out.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/apa-paper-format-TC010076323.aspx

Download link is in Green. You can figure out the rest.